# Working with dialog boxes in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Winforms application that has a message box. When the user clicks the "Generate Report" button, there's a question that's displayed in the message box with `Yes` and `No` as options.

No matter what the user clicks, whether Yes or No, I don't want the report to be generated.

But on the other hand, I want the user to click on the generate button again to generate the report.

How do I do this in C# and Winforms?

Comment: So what exactly is the question? Whether you should do it or not? Or how to do it?

Comment: Tell me if I'm right: the first time the user clicks on Generate, it will show a Yes/No MessageBox of which the result is discarded, and no report is generated. The second time the user clicks on Generate (after dismissing the MessageBox), the report is generated.

Comment: What is the purpose of the messagebox then?  Why don't you just discard that?

Comment: @adamjford u r right. thats what i want. and that is what the user wants.

Comment: Just add this line to your zero utility app: `Application.Exit();`

Comment: @Jani, then why not just generate the report if the user presses yes?  I think it's pretty bad practice if the user is given an option of yes/no and then nothing is done with the result.  Surely there are better ways to achieve this?

Comment: Just to note that this is really poor UI design. It's like a "Do you want to delete?", "Are you really really sure you want to delete?". If I click 'Yes' the first time I generally mean Yes. For some situations like deletion we want to be able to revert (e.g. recycle bin). In this case I imagine there are no consequences that we need to worry about, other than the needless generation of a report.

Comment: I don't understand why the question got downvoted so harshly. The question was unclear at first but reggie is a new user and the question was promptly clean up. And I don't think we should be downvoting because his customer's requirements are stupid.

Comment: To the haters: perhaps the message which pops up has nothing to do with whether or not to display the report... maybe it's something like "Can't generate report yet, have you done x?" And he just wants to gather info on x. Maybe it's a poor design, but it doesn't make his question poor. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use boolean flag:

```
private bool _isClicked = false;

public void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!_isClicked)
   {
        // do show the message box here 
        _isClicked = true;
        return;
   }

   //generate the report here   
   _isClicked = false;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just store a flag in your application - set it to true when you want the button to actually generate the report.  Then when the user clicks the button, you can check the flag and show the MessageBox if the flag isn't set, then set the flag based on the response.  If the flag is set, then generate the report.